# will too many ajax calls affect on my website after hosting

Tags: jquery, web-hosting

I created a chat website which has many ajax(jquery) calls, when i uploaded it on one free web hosting site(000webhosting.com) it is creating problems,its too slow as compared to localhost n plus sometimes one might have to refresh it twice or thrice to get the particular page loaded.

I want to know that is it because of multiple ajax call or a problem of internet speed or it happens with free web hosting (000webhosting.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Internet hosted site will always be slower than `localhost` because the traffic actually has to cross the Internet.  This will be as true in Amazon's cloud as it is for cheap host.

Of course, once you get past basic latency issues you will probably also see perfomance differences between different hosts, but I think your basic problem here is network latency, and possibly bandwidth.